# how to get history of metrics using Sagemaker SDK

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

In sagemaker

```
estimator.training_job_analytics.dataframe()
```

allows you to get a dataframe that contains the final value for every metric, but how to get the history of values for the metrics? I'm looking for something similar to what keras allows using

```
history = model.fit(X,y)
plt.plot(history.history["val_accuracy"]
```

but for sagemaker buil-in training jobs using sagemaker SDK

Answer (score 1):

I beleive there is no direct way to get the metric stream. One way I could think of is since SageMaker uses cloudwatch metrics to track these you can use cloudwatch boto3 getmetricsData API to retrieve - https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch/paginator/GetMetricData.html